# Suspicious access to my Gmail account from "Authorized Application"

Tags: gmail, google-account, security

In the lower right corner of my Gmail page, there a link to see the access history and activities for my account. In the list, I discovered an entry of access from "Authorized Application (427071021612.apps.googleusercontent.com)" and its location is from Virginia.  How to find out what really is that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to https://myaccount.google.com/security#connectedapps and under Apps connected to your account, select Manage Apps and go through the list. There is no good way to interpret the code as what which specific app.

If you suspect something is out of whack, go through the [Google Security Checkup](https://security.google.com/settings/security/secureaccount), change your password, and enable two-step authentication if it isn't already enabled.

Comment: This is the correct answer, but it really bugs me that Google allows apps with names like this, and doesn't give any way to look up what this actually is.  In this particular case, I'm pretty sure that 427071021612.apps.googleusercontent.com is actually IFTTT.

Comment: Can confirm that I'm using IFTTT and that I'm seeing connections from the same server, `427071021612.apps.googleusercontent.com`

Comment: Now you can use Google API to interpret the code https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/apps/get?apix_params=%7B%22appId%22%3A%22974281765361%22%7D#try-it

Answer (score 1):

I found that it was linked to a work iphone that has not only my work emails on it, but my personal Gmail as well.  If you have more than one device (tablet, laptop, smartphone, etc.), and they are all linked to your Google account, you will find this access information under that "details" for your Gmail account.
I think it's kind of neat that Google informs us of that!  It's a great security feature on their part!

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar case with another app. Google support wasn't of much help identifying the app, and the Marketplace search engine does not support searching by id. But we've been able to find it with a Google search:

```
marketplace "[id]"
```

For example:

```
marketplace "260457348581"
```

The first result is for *SketchUp for Schools* on Marketplace.

Then again, not all applications are on Marketplace, like 427071021612 reported by the OP.

This is not a perfect solution but it should help in some (most?) cases.