# Unauthorized access to my Gmail Account

Tags: gmail, google-account, security

From many years I am seeing suspicious activities in my Gmail account. Without my permission my account is getting accessed by someone or by some application. Currently, in my access type I am seeing accessed by 'Authorised Application Ireland (63.32.90.217)'.

I am living in Pune & Satara from Maharashtra,India.How it shows Ireland? It shows my browser type with this 'Authorised Application    Ireland (63.32.90.217)'.

Can you please help me how can I track?

Answer (score 1):

Google has a tool to do an account security checkup

https://myaccount.google.com/security-checkup

It will show a list of security checkpoints. Each of them will contain a list of items to be reviewed by you including a link to a help article that explain each risk.

Related

- [Suspicious access to my Gmail account from "Authorized Application"](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/91536/88163)